# DSolve 4 variables function error

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Mathematica version: 12.0.0.0

I'm trying to solve 2 basic differential equations;

```
(*3 variables function f, correct answer)
DSolve[
  {D[f[x1,x2,x3], {x1,1}] == 1, 
   D[f[x1,x2,x3], {x2,1}] == 1, 
   D[f[x1,x2,x3], {x3,1}] == 1},
  f[x1,x2,x3], {x1,x2,x3}]
```

> `{{f[x1,x2,x3] -> x1+x2+x3+Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]}}`

```
(*4 variables function f*, no answer)
DSolve[
  {D[f[x1,x2,x3,x4], {x1,1}] == 1,
   D[f[x1,x2,x3,x4], {x2,1}] == 1, 
   D[f[x1,x2,x3,x4], {x3,1}] == 1, 
   D[f[x1,x2,x3,x4], {x4,1}] == 1}, 
 f[x1,x2,x3,x4], {x1,x2,x3,x4}]
```

> ```
> DSolve[{(f^(1,0,0,0))[x1,x2,x3,x4]==1, (f^(0,1,0,0))[x1,x2,x3,x4]==1, (f^(0,0,1,0))[x1,x2,x3,x4]==1, (f^(0,0,0,1))[x1,x2,x3,x4]==1}, f[x1,x2,x3,x4], {x1,x2,x3,x4}]
> ```

What is the problem?

Comment: same result in 10.4

Comment: `DSolve` often fails to solve simple systems of first-order PDEs.